# Mule Publish Subscribe messages

Tags: mule

Can i get some pointers on mule publishing to subscribed topic. Can the pub/sub module in Mule be used to publish on a topic created on Active MQ. Can somebody point me to some samples on the pub/sub module using different message brokers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule Publish/Subscribe module does not provide ActiveMQ or other JMS integration. It just provides simple memory-based publish-subscribe functionality between Mule flows. Look at the Java class and the test config in GitHub to get an idea of what it's for: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-publish-subscribe

If you want to use ActiveMQ/JMS with Mule, see this tutorial: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-jms-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Anton can we subscribe from topic using Mule ESB?

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe to a JMS topic, and it is very simple. Please see the tutorial I linked to, and instead of step 3, drag a JMS endpoint to the start of a flow. The endpoint will look something like this with a reference to the connector defined in step 2: <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="my.topic" connector-ref="yourConnector"/>